# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default') in release mode

Tags: react-native, release, react-native-ios

App is running properly without any error in debug mode.but its crashing in release mode after splash screen.
and also when i'm trying to archive it,its getting successful archive but im not getting anything under window->organizer

```
2020-02-26 12:51:09.495781+0530 murmur[68026:485288] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.default')

This error is located at:
    in r
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in n
    in PanGestureHandler
    in t
    in t
    in RCTView
    in e
    in n
    in n
    in r
    in n
    in t
    in c
    in Connect(c)
    in RCTView
    in t
    in Styled(t)
    in i
    in n
    in RCTView
    in Portal.Host
    in r
    in RCTView
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in t

This error is located at:
    in n
    in t
    in c
    in Connect(c)
    in RCTView
    in t
    in Styled(t)
    in i
    in n
    in RCTView
    in Portal.Host
    in r
    in RCTView
    in t
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in t', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (e..., stack:
r@868:1244
tr@108:43619
Nr@108:56528
Ur@108:56960
ui@108:61804
oi@108:61224
ri@108:60352
Ir@108:59332
di@108:66528
render@108:69158
<unknown>@289:440
run@285:601
runApplication@285:2051
value@18:3241
<unknown>@18:824
value@18:2510
value@18:796
value@<null>:<null>
'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm using "react-native": "^0.56.0"

and using "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.5", for navigation

Comment: please post the code too

Comment: which component code u require?